# How to get class names of an installed application using packageManager

Tags: android, class, package

I know how to get package name of installed application using packageManager . But how to get class names in that package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Context` to get the PackageName as well as class name. Try this out->

```
context.getPackageName();

context.getPackageManager().getClass();
```

Comment: Hi, I want to get class names of any other application installed in the mobile. Pleas tell me hoe to do this. Using packageManager class we can get package names of all apps installed in the mobile.Now I want to get all class names in the particular packages

Comment: I wonder why this is the accepted answer. It's clearly wrong! getClass() will return "the unique instance of Class that represents this object's class", in other words, an instance of class PackageManager

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can do that. Class names inside an installed package are usually private data not destined to be shared with anyone and viewed.

On the otherhand, if it would be some .jar file with a public API, you could include in you're project and use it's exposed functionality.

Comment: Hi, I think this is possible. Using packageManager class , I am getting package names and other information of inatalled apps. to get class names we can use packageInfo.activities. But I dont  know how to use this,because it is giving null pointer exception. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html